# Managed beans with custom ViewScope

Tags: spring, jsf-2, view-scope

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. I use PrettyFaces 3.3.2 for friendly URL. The application run on Tomcat 6.35 .

I wanted to use the Jsf ViewScope so I decided to follow the implementation found on the web : http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/

```
public class ViewScope implements Scope {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ViewScope.class);

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        final Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();

        Object instance = viewMap.get(name);
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = objectFactory.getObject();
            viewMap.put(name, instance);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
        logger.debug("ViewScope::remove {}", name);
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
        //Not supported
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I notice that `@PreDestroy` are not called on them like show this question [@PreDestroy never called on @ViewScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368840/predestroy-never-called-on-viewscoped).

**Does it mean that the Managed beans with ViewScope are never destruct ? Which conduct to memory leak. Should we use this scope so?**

**It's only happen with custom Viewscope on Spring or also on Mojarra ?**

Thanks.

Comment: On mojarra the @PreDestroy is called, at least it does in my propyect. I think you will save lot of troubles if you use pure JSF 2 backing beans.

Comment: @IturPablo Do you use Spring in your project ?

Comment: Yess!!!,  I you could use the JSF tags and to access the service beans provided use @ManageProperty("#{}") tag. In my opinion is better use pure JSF beans you avoid some troubles and you are sure about the jsf version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is incorrect implementaiton of view scope.  It is creates Spring bean `objectFactory.getObject();` but never destroy it.

To solve it - check [correct implementation](https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes/blob/master/primefaces-scopes-test/src/main/java/org/nkey/primefaces/scopes/test/spring/scope/ViewScope.java) with support for `registerDestructionCallback`.

BWT, current Mojjara implementation will not call `@PreDestory` on your bean [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368840/predestroy-never-called-on-viewscoped).
But it will free bean instance at least.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the work around for Jsf view scope bean memory leaks using spring custom view scope. It works for both Jsf 2.1 & 2.2.Try the code in below link.
[Memory leak with ViewScoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182844/memory-leak-with-viewscoped-bean)