# Destroying view-scoped beans when session ends

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, view-scope

My question is related to this one (and probably others):

[@PreDestroy never called on @ViewScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368840/predestroy-never-called-on-viewscoped)

As stated there, there's no trivial solution to either have view-scoped beans destroyed upon navigation and the same seems to hold true for when the session expires.

What would a non-trivial approach to release (calling the `@PreDestroy` method) JSF view-scoped beans look like, or more specifically as soon as the session expires?

I'm using Java EE 6 and Mojarra 2.1.x on GlassFish 3.1.2.

Comment: What's the concrete reason for having the beans destroyed?

Comment: Cleanups like deleting temp files that were uploaded (attachments) before the user went to lunch (session expiry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `@SessionScoped` bean to hold the resources (in some collection/array?) and inject it in the `@ViewScoped` bean and then rely on the `@PreDestroy` of the session scoped bean.

True, this way the resources live a little longer than you want, but that's the most easy and reliable solution you can get. If you want to keep the `@PreDestroy` in the view scoped bean, then you'd need to somehow make sure that the enduser always performs navigation by a HTTP POST request on exactly this view scoped bean. You can't reliably guarantee that (the enduser's PC might crash and so on).