# Interlinked View Scoped beans not destroyed up on session invalidate in Jboss Server

Tags: spring, jsf, jboss

I am developing primefaces portlets on liferay jboss server.

In my application I am using several View Scoped Beans which are linked to each other. When we tried doing a load test the Heap Memory was increasing and the server was getting stalled. When I went through the Heap Dump I could see all the view scoped beans not being destroyed. I also tried linking a Session Scoped bean into the view scoped beans so that they would be destroyed. But to my surprise, I could see the session scoped bean is also not getting destroyed and also it is being initialized for every view I injected into. The beans are destroyed fine on Tomcat, but I see this issue on Jboss alone.

I am using Mojarra 2.1.21 + primefaces 4.0.

Could anyone please help where I am going wrong. I have been googling a lot but could not find a solution from past 3 days.

Comment: It's a known issue :http://stackoverflow.com/a/13097208/1530938. Basically you'll have to upgrade or handle cleanup yourself in a listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by changing the implementation of WebInjectionContainer in jboss-as-web-7.1.1-final.jar. I have changed the STRONG reference type to WEAK reference for the concurrentHashMap and now the beans are destroyed upon session expiration or logout.