# JSF2 @ViewScoped beans never destroyed

Tags: jsf-2, memory-leaks, mojarra

i have already spent 3 days searching for a possible workaround, so my ViewScoped beans do not lead to an OutOfMemoryException, but without any luck.

First my environment:
JBoss AS 7.1.1.final with
Mojarra 2.1.7

I thought, that ViewScoped beans would be destroyed on a session expiration, but they will not get destroyed (checked with heap dumps). I found the following new feature for Mojarra 2.1.16, which fixes this problem, but sadly upgrading to this version is currently not an option:
http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2561

This problem is also related to the following thread:
[Destroying view-scoped beans when session ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082379/destroying-view-scoped-beans-when-session-ends)

Is there anything i can do, to remove all created ViewScoped beans, when a session ends (logout or session expired)? Saving viewMap in a SessionScoped bean and call clear() also not destroy those beans.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Is your concrete problem that the `@PreDestroy` of a view scoped bean is never called on session expire (which is what issue 2561 has fixed; please note that the problem is merely the method invocation, not the actual destroy!), or is it that they persist in memory even after session expire? The latter should be absolutely not the case. They should not be referenced anywhere and be GC'ed sooner or later. Are you sure that you aren't referencing them elsewhere yourself? Are you absolutely positive that you've properly observed the concrete problem?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. The problem is the latter one. After the session is expired, the @ViewScoped beans persist in memory. To trigger an OOM-Error i simply write a JMeter testcase, which logs in and out with 50 Threads and use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to create a heap dump at the end. The heap dump was full of ViewScoped beans, which have also SessionScoped beans attached.

Comment: Okay, are those session scoped beans in turn referenced elsewhere? E.g. in an application scoped bean?

Comment: Yes, but like i pointed out in my answer, it also happens for view scoped beans without any references.

Answer (score 0):

To nail down this bug i have stripped my code to the following parts:

One JSF2 page that is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Simple OOM Check</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="#{oomCheckBean.testString}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the used @ViewScoped bean oomCheckBean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "oomCheckBean")
public class OomCheckBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6325712415478215045L;

    private String testString;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        testString = "Hello World";
        System.out.println("I will survive ....");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("... klaaatsch!");
    }

    /**
     * @return the testString
     */
    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    /**
     * @param testString the testString to set
     */
    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}
```

After this i changed my JMeter testcase to login, call this oomCheck.xhtml page and logout. After a short time i stopped test execution, and used JMX to first call manually the garbage collector (*java.lang.Memory --> Operations --> gc()*). After this i call method to create a heap dump (*com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnostic --> Operations --> dumpHeap()*).

Result is like i mentioned in my question, there are a lot OomCheckBean objects in memory. The owner object is `org/jboss/as/web/deployment/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$HashEntry`. Any help to fix this problem is appreciated. Like i mentioned above, these @ViewScoped beans will be destroyed, if JSF version is upgraded to 2.1.16, leaving other "bugs" like missing doctype and AJAX problems. So i would be happy, if someone knows how to destroy @ViewScoped beans, when session becomes invalid.

Comment: Hi , did you happen to get around the issue without upgrading to 2.1.16 ?

Comment: Thank's for your feedback :) Just a question, @ViewScoped are destroyed only when you logout or also when after several others page accesses (with 'com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession' and 'com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews') ?